# Fetching Office Documents from Google Cloud Storage and showing on JSP

Tags: jsp, google-cloud-storage

I am working on a requirement, where users can upload Images, PDF, Docs, XCEL, PPT files etc from their machine using the web application on Google Cloud Storage. My web application (JSP) should also be able to display their previously uploaded documents.

On JSP, user will have an option to click the link and the respective file should be displayed on JSP.

My question is how to show the respective document on JSP, when they click on it. The client machine might not have suitable software for PDF, Microsoft docs, xls, PPT etc. Is there a facility with Google Cloud Storage to resolve this problem.

If yes, then any sample application to retrieve documents from Google Cloud and display them on browser would be helpful.

Please share your thoughts on it.

Thanks !!
Gagan

Comment: If the user doesn't have anything to read that kind of file, the only way around that is for you to provide a flash app that can on your site.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Can you give me some more information or directions on what kind of flash app you are suggesting. Any examples will be helpful. - Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

If user owns these docs, I'd suggest to save these on user's google drive and use the preview function of google drive. All the file formats supported by drive can be shown without the viewer applications intalled on user's machine then.

[Supported file types](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2423485):

- Image files (.JPEG, .PNG, .GIF, .TIFF, .BMP)
- Video files (WebM, .MPEG4, .3GPP, .MOV, .AVI, .MPEGPS, .WMV, .FLV)
- Text files (.TXT)
- Markup/Code (.CSS, .HTML, .PHP, .C, .CPP, .H, .HPP, .JS)
- Microsoft Word (.DOC and .DOCX)
- Microsoft Excel (.XLS and .XLSX)
- Microsoft PowerPoint (.PPT and .PPTX)
- Adobe Portable Document Format (.PDF)
- Apple Pages (.PAGES)
- Adobe Illustrator (.AI)
- Adobe Photoshop (.PSD)
- Tagged Image File Format (.TIFF)
- Autodesk AutoCad (.DXF)
- Scalable Vector Graphics (.SVG)
- PostScript (.EPS, .PS)
- TrueType (.TTF)
- XML Paper Specification (.XPS)
- Archive file types (.ZIP and .RAR)
- .MTS files